# Why are there so many well-kept ancient VW pick-ups on La Palma?

Tags: automobiles, local-customs, factoids, canary-islands, nostalgia

I've been recently on the beautiful island of La Palma, and in the rural areas, I noticed a considerable number of similarly-styled cars (same grey, all pick-ups), namely VW T2 pick-ups, which looked like this, but in even better shape:

[image: VW T2 Pic-up]

Is there a story behind this? Are these ex-army vehicles which have been sold to farmers in lieu of better ways of disposal? Are these cars (the last of which has been manufactured in 1979) just that good for agricultural work on a volcanic island?

Picture by Robotriot (Own Work) [GFDL (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) or CC BY-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)], via Wikimedia Commons

Comment: Welcome! I don't think this is a question about travel; rather, it's a question about the habits and customs of people in a particular place. If this is travel, then almost any question about any group of people is travel, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the habits and customs of people in a particular place. The only connection to travel is that the asker was travelling when the question occurred to them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You have a point. But then, what about the series of questions concerning the use of a bidet? Were they off-topic, too? Is there any other SE site where this might be mirgrated to because it suits better?

Comment: I'm not aware of any SE sites where the question would be on-topic. My own feeling is that the bidet question is off-topic, too, though at least that's a question about how to use facilities that are available to you, rather than a question about things that the locals do. Of course, it may be that I'm the only person who thinks this is off-topic.

Comment: @DavidRicherby We have plenty of similar questions, e.g. "[Why 00 is the German bathroom symbol](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71995/why-is-this-bathroom-symbol-in-germany-00)". This is on-topic.

Comment: Part of the reason is that it is an island, it will be harder to take them off than to repair and keep using them. And it will also be more expensive to bring in replacements, so what is there is more valuable than it would be in a bigger market area.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: If we want to find a reason how this is travel-specific, that is well possible: For instance, from the angle of someone who *looks for* seeing this old car type in use, and thus searches for locations where it can be found, the reasons why these cars are currently widespread in a given location can be relevant (as it is also an indication whether they are likely still in use in 2, 5, 10, ... years from now, and whether it is, for instance, likely to find one for rent or other purposes).

Comment: @Roland a bidet and the use of it is a problem faced by travellers who need to use one and have never seen one before.  A general wondering about a type of vehicle - not so much, IMHO. Voting to close as well.

Comment: Why a place has lots of old VWs or [a building is decorated with swastikas](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78716) are both curiosity questions, not problems travellers face. You can ask them on Quora but not on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think we may need to address curiosity questions in our official scope FAQ page. We can cover the caveat about factoid questions that are the main exception. Also, [tag;nostalgia], WTF has that got to do with travel??

Comment: By the way, Laos, or at least Vientiane has lots of VW beetles in every state from trash to treasure. Cambodia has tons of almost new Lexuses. I'm super curious about both of those but I'm not asking here on TSE because things I notice while I'm travelling are not necessarily travel questions.

Comment: @hippietrail Can you please link to the meta thread where it was decided that only questions about negative problems were allowed? Because this looks like a local customs question to me. These were [discussed very recently, and the majority view seemed to be to allow them](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/3864/3145). Cuba's famous for its old cars, for example, they're a major attraction, it'd be crazy if questions about that wasn't allowed; so I don't see why this isn't allowed?

Comment: @DavidRicherby What you're describing is a local customs question. [We've got 171 of them](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-customs). They're on topic.

Comment: Not customs. Customs are traditional ways of a people passed generation to generation as part of their culture. Shaking hands, wearing shoes in the house, cheek kissing, etc. Not every type of thing than can vary between to places is culture, such as what happens to be cool or fashionable or prevalent for whatever of a myriad reasons.