# What is the meaning of the swastikas at Ny Carlsberg Glyptotek museum in Copenhagen, Denmark?

Tags: museums, denmark, history, copenhagen

I travelled to Copenhagen, Denmark recently.  On one side of the [Ny Carlsberg Glyptotek museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ny_Carlsberg_Glyptotek) is a park.  The entrance to the park has swastikas embedded in the metal gate posts.

[image: Google Streetview Reference 1.]
([Google Streetview Reference 1.](https://www.google.com/maps/@55.6719136,12.5723848,3a,75y,270h,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sjV1reKsIvMxpmgG8JCJ_5Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656))

Also, on the side this brick building embedded with the bricks or granite stonework (I cannot precisely remember) are more swastikas.

[image: Google Streetview reference 2.]
([Google Streetview reference 2.](https://www.google.com/maps/@55.6720719,12.5706928,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sswc12oKrXP1N_Izfdh4AIA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656))

What is the meaning or history behind these swastikas in this complex?

So that my intent is clear, I realise:

- Europe has a complicated history with swastikas from the era of the German National Socialist Party.
- Swastikas have different meanings given their angle / tilt / mirror.

Comment: Swastikas had no negative connotations until the 1930's. The museum was opened in 1897. There would be nothing surprising or strange about swastikas as a decorative element in the 19th century.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I don't think swastikas _really_ went out of fashion until the early/mid-forties in Europe, and it's worth noting that in India, China, and related areas they are still quite popular indeed (which tends to cause a bit of cross-cultural mixup in international commerce).

Comment: @WillihamTotland In India, they are one of the most popular religious symbols, like the cross for Christians. In every Hindu ritual, the Swastika is the 1st thing drawn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about architecture, design, and history; not about travel. Questions asking about finding, visiting, tickets, opening hours of museums are about travel. Questions asking about why they were decorated a certain way back when they were built are not about travel. Being an interesting question does not make it an on-topic question.

Comment: This symbol is also found on other (New) Carlsberg architecture from long before the Nazi time. Notably, the [Elephant Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_Gate_and_Tower,_Carlsberg) which is part of the New Carlsberg brewery itself, [features it](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Elefantporten_-_detail_1.jpg).

Comment: For the chronology, see also [Wikipedia: swastika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika) which also mentions Carlsberg. Note that (Old) Carlsberg was founded in 1847 by J. C. Jacobsen who named it after his son, Carl Jacobsen, who was 5 years old at the time. Then New Carlsberg was founded by Carl himself in 1882. The two competing breweries were merged in 1906. The Nazi Party adopted the swastika symbol in 1920.

Comment: @hippietrail  Can you please link to the meta thread where the community agreed on this narrow scope? In every related discussion I've seen, this narrow interpretation wasn't popular

Comment: @user568458: Please link to a meta thread where the community agrees to just how broad the scope is then. There's lots of things I'm curious about here in Taiwan. Should I just start posting them all because I'm travelling? I got into trouble even for having a troublesome padlock a month ago. So it was pretty narrow a month ago. Anyway tell us where you see the limit. So far the impression is that you think there should be no limit and that 'i was travelling and got curious' is always on topic.

Comment: @hippietrail If your Taiwan questions fit `local customs` or `identify this`, or if like this they're about maximising a visit to an attraction to roughly "guidebook" level and would fit `museums` or similar, please do ask! On-topic questions that fit a tag don't become off topic just because the motivation was curiosity rather than frustration. If they don't fit any of these, they're probably off topic (regardless of motivation - motivation's irrelevant). If anything's unclear, feel free to open a new meta thread.

Comment: I don't have questions about local customs right now although the specifics of the shoes in various parts of hostels is something I wish I knew I haven't thought up a good SE wording for the question. Identify this has its own set of rules. I've seen a good few Chinese characters I'm curious about, I've seen dishes at restaurants I'm curious about, I've seen menu items in Chinese or Chinglish that I'm curious about. There is no concept of question 'fitting a tag' on SE. Tags are there to fit questions. We have an automobiles tag. I'm curious about all the imitation mini VW combis in Taiwan.

Comment: All possible questions about automobiles and museums don't become travel questions because we have automobile and museum tags. It's very clear.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[Regarding the Ny Carlsberg Glyptotek:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ny_Carlsberg_Glyptotek)

> The collection is built around the personal collection of **Carl
> Jacobsen** (1842–1914), the son of the founder of the **Carlsberg**
> Breweries.

According to the same source, parts of the museum were originally *Carlsberg's private villa*. The rest of what is now the museum then formed around the villa.

The Carlsberg Group's [official website states](http://www.carlsberggroup.com/Company/heritage/architectureatCarlsberg/Pages/SymbolsontheCarlsbergGrounds.aspx):

> The Swastika is an ancient symbol of prosperity and goodness
> in Sanskrit. **In 1881 Carl Jacobsen made it the symbol of the beer
> produced in his brewery** 'Ny Carlsberg' which was a competitor to his
> father's 'Old Carlsberg' brewery.
>
> **Carl had a profound interest in
> ancient Greece and Rome where the symbol was also often used.**
>
> In 1940 Carlsberg stopped using the swastika symbol for good.

Apparently, the particular type of [gates referred to in OP are from 1882.](http://oldcastiron.blogspot.in/2016/02/iron-gates-of-copenhagen-wrought-and.html?view=timeslide&m=1) As you suggest in OP, this was certainly before the Swastika had acquired the negative associations it presently carries (in the West.)

[image: Gate from 1882.]
<sup>[Image source](http://oldcastiron.blogspot.in/2016/02/iron-gates-of-copenhagen-wrought-and.html?view=timeslide&m=1)</sup>

There are also other Swastikas and [Sauwastikas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauwastika) in the museum:

[image: Swastika in ceiling.]
<sup>[Image source](https://svasticross.blogspot.in/2010/10/swastika-ny-carlsberg-glyptotek.html?m=1)</sup>

[image: Swastika in concrete.]

<sup>[Image source](http://nork.ru/others/copenhagen.html)</sup>

<sup>The emphasis is mine in both quotes.</sup>

Comment: Perfect.  The first and third photo match exactly what I saw during my visit.

Comment: It's worth noting that the first and the second images are "Swastika" but the third one isn't.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma how is the third not a swastika? It's a left-hand swastika, to be sure, and not the more familiar (in modern/western context) right-hand swastika, but as far as I know it's still a swastika.

Comment: @DoktorJ I think you're right. It's a Sauwastika. But I think Sauwastikas are also a type of Swastikas, right?

Comment: @DoktorJ: I'm an Indian; the 3rd is not a swastik, at least not in the sense the word "swastik" was associated with Hindu culture. The Carlsberg website specifically mentions "The Swastika is an ancient symbol of prosperity and goodness in Sanskrit" and I'm pretty sure there is only a single way to re-present Swastik; there is no "left-hand" swastik.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma Check out [this article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauwastika) There is certainly a counterclockwise Swastika. It's used a lot in Buddhism. It's certainly not as common in Hinduism, but it does exist there also.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma [Buddhist temple with counterclockwise Swastika](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Swastika-seoel_(xndr).jpg).

Comment: Just because the symbol may appear on a Buddhist temple doesn't mean it is a Swastika.  According to the source of knowledge which is always true and accurate, [Wikipedia's article on Swastika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika) notes, "four legs bent at 90 degrees", and Nazi's used "A mirrored left sided swastika".  I would tend to call the other version a "Manji" ([Wikipedia's article on Manji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manji)), though I may be heavily biased from familiarity w/ a Japanese product, Zelda 1 (1st example of [Zelda Controversy](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Controversy))

Comment: @TOOGAM The Wikipedia article you refer to features several pictures of counterclockwise ones, indeed referring to them as Swastikas. The Manji icon you refer to on Wikipedia even links to the Swastika article.

Comment: Fiksdal : I don't doubt it.  I figured my statements showed more support for your stance than @SanjayT.Sharma 's.  Are you somehow trying to counter/dispute me?  What is the point you're making by rehashing the claims?

Comment: @TOOGAM I must have misunderstood your statements, I thought you were trying to argue the view of Sanjay T. Sharma.

Comment: @TOOGAM : I guess misleading naming convention all round; I'm almost sure that the origin of the symbol lies in Hindu culture and the rest of the "similar" structures were self proclaimed "variations" of Swastika. I would be interested if someone can point me to a historical textbook from a non-hindu origin which mentions swastika and the reason why it was called so...

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma The [etymology of *Swastika*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=swastika) is "from Sanskrit svastika-s, literally "being fortunate," from svasti-s "well-being, luck," from su- "well" (from PIE *(e)su- "good") + as-, root of asti "(he) is," which is from the same PIE root as Latin esse "to be" (see essence). "

Answer (score 47):

The Carlsberg brewery started using the swastika as their logo in 1881. After the nazis adopted the swastika as their most prominent symbol, Carlsberg stopped using it some time in the 1930ies, but it is still in place on some of their older buildings, e.g. at the Glypotek musuem.

Here is an example of an old Carlsberg beer bottle label:

[image]

Comment: This particular label is from 1902 (New Carlsberg). See [Lys Skattefri](http://øletiket.dk/hvidt_ol_skattefri_carlsberg_lys.htm) or [Lys og Mørk Carlsberg - Skattefri](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.769250376533926.1073741833.768033619988935) (both with text in Danish).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen What's the deal with skattefri? Did some beer have tax and some not?

Comment: @Fiksdal The Danish text in my last link says (my translation): _In 1891, beer taxes had been introduced in Denmark. However, there was no taxation of beer with an alcohol percentage under 2.8; therefore Carl Jacobsen named his beer Light and Dark Tax-Free Beer. The beer caught on quite well even in teetotal circles. In 1917, taxation legislation was changed and now these beer types became taxable as well. Tax-Free was rebranded as "New Pilsner"._

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Very interesting, takk.