# Why are wheelie bins half-buried in parts of Luxembourg?

Tags: local-customs, factoids, cultural-awareness, luxembourg

Walking around a residential area in Luxembourg, I noticed that each home had their wheelie bin for general rubbish in the front yard strangely placed in a neat, concrete-lined pit.

[image: Some random front yard with a half-buried bin]

It wasn't everywhere in Luxembourg, but nor was it just one home-owner - I saw at least 20 properties in a row that had it, suggesting it was a local ordinance rather than a personal choice.

I have shown this photo to many Europeans, who have expressed surprise and come up with many wild speculations, but I haven't found a Luxembourger to explain the practice.

Why are the rubbish bins "buried" in this way?

Comment: Wind blows them over sometimes and stray animals, especially urban foxes, can tip them over. This idea can prevent both.  I would expect also there's an overarching cultural aspiration that 'everything has a proper place'  and this approach complements that aspiration, but that part's a guess.

Comment: @GayotFow: Yes, several people have come up with similar speculations to me that wind and dogs are the reason. I have asked them "You don't bury your bins. Has this ever been a problem for you?", and they have all said "No", so it seems unlikely, especially as it would be more effort to remove. It also doesn't explain why every single property in the area had the exact same solution.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't explain it?

Comment: I thought I just gave two reasons: (1) It is an expensive (in terms of effort) solution to what appears to be a non-problem. (2) I would expect each home-owner to decide for themselves, which would lead to non-uniformity amongst Luxembourgers, and more prevalence in other countries. [If you really think this is an answer, please post it as one.]

Comment: Were the buried ones the same size as the non-buried ones?  I know of cases in the US where the smallest trash cans provided for houses were skinny and top heavy, falling over for all sorts of reasons (dogs, wind, etc).  But rather than digging holes, they cut the bottoms off (there was an inner container that held the garbage) and made them shorter.  The two bigger capacity trash cans were not effected.

Comment: @Tom: They were all buried. I would guess they were around the 80-120L range. They also had small (about 40L?) ones for glass (I think) that were designed to be wheeled by the resident to a collection point nearby. I don't know what they did for other recycling types.

Comment: Why do you think it's expensive?  Or that "every single property" has one?  A contractor could install one in less than an hour and if they were in a neighbourhood sweep in an affluent community it could help explain why lots of people signed up.  Monkey see, monkey do.

Comment: If it was limited to specific areas, it could have been a neighborhood agreement, due to local conditions (lots of stray dogs, wind channeling down the street, etc)

Comment: @GayotFow: I mean expensive in the effort to remove the rubbish bin from the pit. Lifting a bin full of rubbish straight up is hard work. [Maybe there is some hidden mechanism to help?] So, I wouldn't expect it to be done unless it makes a big difference. I noticed one property had it, and then continued walking and found that every property I walked past had it (my walking wound through backstreets) - I photographed maybe the dozenth one I saw, so I could ask about the practice. That experience is limited to one suburb, but it was completely ubiquitous there.

Comment: OK, I think your question is well-intended but that you are after a more elaborate answer than what's immediately obvious.  I'll post a close vote in favour of our collateral relative 'Home Improvement'. http://diy.stackexchange.com/  If you think it's really a travel question, please edit your question to make the connection explicit, thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the connection to travel is missing, and "Home Improvement" is more competent http://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a problem faced by travellers.

Comment: @hippietrail then we should also close this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71995/why-is-this-bathroom-symbol-in-germany-00

Comment: How do you get your bin to the street when its full and heavy?

Comment: @JonathanReez I've [posted about this](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3862/41775) on meta.

Comment: So it turns out that the placement of rubbish bins at a private residence  is a regulated subject.  Nice to know if one is a home owner in Luxembourg, but still off topic @JonathanReez

Comment: Before the local municipality supplied organics bins with locking tops (to deter the ubiquitous dexterous raccoons) we hung ours on the side of the house when it was not out for collection. Otherwise they would find a way to knock it over and get into it. Since 'coons are nocturnal it was no problem when the bin was streetside for collection.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Indeed. Though it is worded as a curiosity question it does actually have value as a travel question for those not aware that this a bathroom sign. I voted it up because the overall QA provided toilet finding info even though the OP already knew what it means and asked about its history.

Comment: Is that in Luxembourg city?

Comment: @Relaxed: Yes. Kirchberg if I am not mistaken. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchberg,_Luxembourg

Comment: Interesting. Here are Googe Street view photos of the same road (in the same area) taken on different days. The bins are out on the road in one, and in their places in the other. https://www.google.com/maps/@49.635248,6.165207,3a,75y,298.29h,74.2t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sdVUUnllFLs3mchXd1D3dXQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656  https://www.google.com/maps/@49.6352497,6.1650682,3a,15y,18.53h,74.98t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1syvEEk6m3Xwmjg7CTW6DN-w!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Comment: At my mums house in Australia, we have a bin exactly like this filled with compost and food scraps for the garden. Did you try asking the residents of the house what it is for? Because this would more than likely come down to a personal use preference.

Comment: Bins are ugly. Making them appear smaller makes then less ugly. Some elderly or infirm people have difficulty lifting objects. Half-burying the bins lowers the tops to make them easier to use without reducing the useable volume.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44727/discussion-on-question-by-oddthinking-why-are-wheelie-bins-half-buried-in-luxemb).

Comment: Then extra work for the waste collectors to pull the bins.

Comment: My first thought on seeing the photo was "wheel chair bound owner". Those properties may be sheltered housing for elderly, infirm or disabled persons who still want to live independently.

Comment: @Moo Nope. These are "normal" houses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a problem faced by travellers.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer, they are not.

It's something specific to that house.

Edit: I'm from Luxembourg and have never seen this, or perhaps only in isolated cases. It's certainly nothing national.

Comment: Question clearly mentions 20 houses in a row that had it.

Comment: Then it is to that neighbourhood. I have been living in Luxembourg for 32 years and have never seen this.

Comment: That's why I asked in a comment about the municipality. What you write is partly true, but that's still not an explanation. Specific to this neighbourhood or not, what is it?

Comment: I would say order. Some have some enclosures above ground, and this one is slightly in the ground. It might not be super smart though.

Comment: If you take a virtual drive around Kirchberg in [Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/@49.6352535,6.1647627,3a,25.9y,24.06h,70.4t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sFPGtd9Rr-PsyDJZbv66h5g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) you will see this is ubiquitous in the area. (Beware: It's harder to tell when the photos are taken on collection day, though.)

Comment: @Oddthinking: Your claim is not true. It's definitely not ubiquitous in Kirchberg. There are some houses  where ot is the case and these house are in the small area bezween boulevard Pierre Frieden and the Luxexpo.

Comment: @AndréPeseur: Ha! The plot thickens. I've been touring around Kirchberg with Google Street View and peering in people's front gardens and you are right! This phenomena is localised to just part of Kirchberg. This gets weirder and weirder.

Comment: Sometimes there are plans for building a whole neighborhood to create a consistent looking area. It could be that this happened. The houses etc should in principle look similar from architecture point if view. That's my best guess at this point

Comment: The neighbourthood we are talking about is the first residential are of the "modern" Kirchberg. These houses have been bulit in the late 1970's and in the early 1980's. That's why the all look similar.

Comment: how does ***the garbage robot truck*** deal with this ?????  the standard garbage robot truck expects the bin to be sitting on the same level as the tyres of the truck.  WTF !?!?

Comment: @JoeBlow you have to life the bin out and out it on the curb.

Comment: Hi @Trefex - thanks, but I'm assuming these are the same size bins as are typical in say the USA (they appear to be from the photo).  It would be absolutely 100% impossible to lift such a bin, even half-full of garbage, from the hole: you'd need say three strong people to do so.  i don't get this???

Comment: I guess I must be wrong - they must be tiny "kitchen bin" size bins.   Another of life's mysteries anyway!

Comment: @JoeBlow yep they are pretty heavy i assume. Fortunately I don't own such a bin hole :)

Answer (score 2):

The houses in this area are pretty small. Some even don't have a garage and neither or a cave that is accessible from outside. Even those houses with a garage are small and storing the dustbin outside saves some space and you are not bothered with bad smells.

Now, letting the dustbins stand outside has two drawbacks:

1. It does not look very nice if you see dustbins all over the place. The landscpae looks much nicer when the bins are buried.
2. These dustbins are relatively high and they can easily fall down when there is heavy wind or when children playing outside (or drunkards walking by) crash into them.

Partially burying the bins solves these problems. And the bins remain accessible.

This may sound weird, but as I said in a comment above, the "phenomenon" is localized to some streets that have been urbanized some 35 years age. If you go to other areas in Luxembourg-Kirchbegr, you will see that they came up with other solutions.